# How can I tell if the elements in an Array List are same or different?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to verify if all the elements in an array list are same or not. This is my code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,2,4,2));
for (int z = 0; z < arr.size(); z++) {          
    if(!arr.get(z++).equals(arr.get(z--))) {
        System.out.println("same"); 
    }else {
        System.out.println("differnt");         
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to know all combinations of elements? Else, just pick any element (the first, for example) and do a single iteration in which you check if all elements are the same as the picked element. If so, then all elements are the same.

Comment: Are you aware of `z++` and `z--` actually modifying `z`? That code looks super complex to read, I strongly advise to not use `++` or `--` in any *clever* way, it is error prone and will confuse readers. If you just need the next or previous element, do `get(z + 1)` and `get(z - 1)`, which does not modify `z`.

Comment: Your question is missing details. You should at least give a clear example, the current output and the desired output. Please read [mcve], [help] and [ask], thanks. In the current state, it is of poor quality and might thus receive down- or even close-votes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put the elements into a `Set`. If the resulting set has a size of 1, then all elements have been the same. One line of code, no loops, no indices, works with every collection:

```
boolean allTheSame = new HashSet<Integer>(list).size() == 1;
System.out.println(allTheSame ? "same" : "different");
```

<sub>(Edited:)</sub>

It might be worth noting that *if* the list is large, and likely contains many different elements, then constructing a `Set` will impose some memory overhead that *can* be avoided, if desired. In this case, you'd iterate over the list and compare all elements to the first one. **But** you should **not** check the elements for identity with `==`. Instead, you should compare them using their `equals` method, or, if you graciously want to handle `null` entries, using `Objects#equals`.

An example of how to solve this efficiently and generically is given in the [answer by  Zabuza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54722897/3182664)

Comment: Depending on the list implementation, using `get(...)` might be very inefficient. Instead, use an `Iterator`, for example with an enhanced for loop.

Comment: @Zabuza That's a valid point. I added the code in the 'edit' a bit hastily. In practice, a solution with generics and an `Iterator` or enhanced `for` loop would be more appropriate. So I edited again, just pointing out the reasoning behind this alternative, and linking to your answer for the code.

Comment: thanks, but I need the output in String format and would be better if also look for combinations

Answer (score 6):

There are various solutions to this.

---

### Compare any with others

You just need to pick any element (the first, for example) and then compare this to all other elements. A single simple loop is enough:

```
public static <E> areElementsEquals(List<E> list) {
    // Edge cases
    if (list == null || list.size() <= 1) {
        return true;
    }

    // Pick any element
    E any = list.get(0);
    // Compare against others
    for (E other : list) {
        // Use Objects#equals for null-safety
        if (!Objects.equals(any, other)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or a Stream-API version:

```
return list.stream()
    .allMatch(other -> Objects.equals(any, other));
```

If you checked that `any` is not `null`, you could also use a method reference:

```
return list.stream()
    .allMatch(any::equals);
```

---

### Set

Sets do not have duplicates. You can put all your elements into a `Set` and check if the size is `1`, then all other elements were duplicates.

```
return new HashSet<>(list).size() == 1;
```

While this code is pretty compact, I would favor the more straightforward solution of iterating. It is a bit more readable and also more efficient, since it does not have the additional overhead of setting up a set.

Answer (score 4):

You only have to compare the 1st item against all the others:

```
int a = arr.get(0);
boolean allSame = true;
for (int z = 1; z < arr.size(); z++) {
    allSame = (a == arr.get(z));
    if (!allSame) break;
}

if (allSame)
    System.out.println("Same");
else
    System.out.println("Different");
```

Comment: Need to add 0-size list check, but overall that's the right way to do this task

Comment: @amseager Why *0-size list check*? The 1st item is already stored in `a`.

Comment: I think he wanted to point out that `arr.get(0)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the list has a size of `0`. (And in general, the code will throw a `NullPointerException` if the list contains `null` entries, due to the autounboxing)

Comment: @Marco13 the above code was based on the OP's sample data (list of 4 integers). A more generalized solution should include more conditions, like *what is the result if the list is empty?*, or *what is the result if the list is filled with nulls?*

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to explain what amseager likely referred to with his comment.

Comment: @Marco13 it's fine. There's always a lot to think about even when dealing with the simplest problem.

Answer (score 4):

. . . and does your code work? What sort of output do you get? Are you suffering any exceptions?
Don't declare your List as ArrayList; declare it as List. Don't call a List `arr;` it isn't an array. Call it `numbers` or something like that.
Why have you got the bang sign/not operator in line 3? I think that shouldn't be there.
If you think about the different kinds of collection/data structure available, which you can read about [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html), you will find a collection type whose `size()` method will tell you how many distinct elements you have.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to compare the current element with the next, if they are different that means you don't have all elements the same:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i) != list.get(i + 1)) {
            return false; // elements are different
        }
    }

return true; // all element are the same
```

Comment: **This will return `false` when the list contains integer values larger than 128**. Try it out with elements like `1000` or so. You should *not* compare references with `!=`. You should use `equals` instead, and in order to easily handle `null` entries, preferably `Objects#equals`. Beyond that, there are better alternatives in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
String first = arr.get(0);
boolean allTheSame = true;
if (arr.size() > 1) {
    for (int z = 1; z < arr.size(); z++) {
        if (!arr.get(z).equals(first)) {
            allTheSame = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to check for each element, if all the elements on later indexes are same as that one or different than it.
You can do it using a nested loop like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,2,4,2));
        boolean result=true;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            for (int j=i; j<arr.size(); j++){
                if (!arr.get(i).equals(arr.get(j))){
                    result=false;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

the 2nd loop starts from `j=i` and goes till the right end of the array because you don't need to check the left side of that index as it is already checked in the previous iterations and the `result` would already have been updated to `false`.

Comment: Unnecessary O(n2) complexity. You can do it with O(n) like @forpas did in his answer

Comment: @amseager I agree but I dont think that the time complexity is the real issue at hand as long as the answer is understood by the questioner.

Comment: Try this out with `Arrays.asList(222,222,222)`. It will print `false`. You should **not** compare references with `!=`.

Answer (score 3):

A method use `BitSet` to judge are all elements in list is same or not,it need less memory and run faster.

```
public static boolean areAllElementsSame(List<Integer> numbers) {
    BitSet set = new BitSet();
    numbers.forEach(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Integer integer) {
            set.set(integer);
        }
    });
    return set.cardinality() == 1;
}
```

This method can also used to figure out how many different elements.

Answer (score 3):

same is a flag that stores the result we intend.
uv is the uniformality variable.
Object is the type of object you stored in list (the arraylist)

```
import java.util.*; 
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,2,2,2));
        boolean same=true;
        Object uv=arr.get(0);
        for (Object i: arr){
            if(!i.equals(uv)){
                same=false;
                break;
            }   
        }
        System.out.print("Result:"+same);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure that the list contains at least two different elements, you have to "walk" the array once: you compare the first element against all others, and stop on the first mismatch. On mismatch: not all elements are the same, otherwise they are all the same!

But the initial question was a bit unclear. If you want to determine if there are **no** two equal elements in the array, you have to compare all entries against all others! Then you need two loops: you pick all elemenst in order, to compare them to all others (respectively to all following ones: you already compared slot 1 to all other slots, so you would only have to compare slot 2 to slot3 ... til end).

Another approach would be to use a Set implementation, for example HashSet! Sets have unique members. So when you turn your list into a set, and the set has less entries than the list, you know that the list contains duplicates.